# Light-activated Expanding Chemicals

Tags: science-based, physics, chemistry, optics

In my world, electricity has not yet been discovered, but they have somehow still managed to attain a technological advancement similar to modern times.

I am currently trying to tackle the problem of photosensors, for usages such as automatic lighting and 'digital' photography.

My current idea would be to have 'cylinders' containing an expanding material, with a lens on one end and delicate pistons on the other, acting as pixels.

The material would expand base on the brightness, and the pistons would pick up on this, translating the light into motion for some regulating mechanism.

**Would it be feasible**, from a chemical point of view, **to have a chemical that expands based on light intensity?**

If so, what other properties might such a material possess?

I am specifically looking for a material which can react to quick changes in light, so most candidates functioning via thermal expansion would be unsuitable.

Comment: you probably want to better define your problem. Thermal expansion happens for any chemicals and temperature increases with exposure to light, but I think you are not looking for such a thing

Comment: @L.Dutch Thank you for the tip.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around modern technology with no electricity... when all it takes is someone to rub their feet on the carpet to discover electricity....

Comment: @Shadowzee Discover electricity perhaps, but by no means understand, let alone harness, it.

Answer (score 4):

There are a vast number of chemical reactions that are triggered by light. The study of these is known as [photochemistry](https://www.britannica.com/science/photochemical-reaction). This includes reactions such as those that occur in photosynthesis. Photosynthetic reactions cause the synthesis of glucose from carbon dioxide and water. As the densities of these materials are different it is clearly possible to trigger a change in density by the application of light.

Another example: concentrated anthracene solution when exposed to light forms a dimer which precipitates from solution (so is of higher density than the surrounding solution). This is another example of a light triggered reaction causing a change in density. 
Although in this case an increase in density. In principle there is no reason why a photochemical reaction should not trigger a decrease in density.

As for what other properties such a substance might have, I doubt there are any specific properties they need to share (other than the ability to absorb light) as the range of photochemical reactions is so vast including everything from photochemical smog gas reactions to the solid state reactions in silver halides used chemical photographic papers.

So changes in density can be triggered by light, but whether those changes are fast enough or large enough to be of use is another question. I would suggest alternative means might be used. Rather than changes in density why not changes in pressure or viscity etc.

Comment: Pressure could still be detected by pistons, so long as the cylinder is airtight. Would you care to elaborate on that point?

Comment: Yes you are correct; with fine enough tolerances very slight expansions or contractions would be detectable via your piston method. However it would be better to use a material that underwent a phase change such as a liquid that decomposed on exposure to light as the pressure would be more easily and accurately detected.

Comment: What kind of chemical could be used and would it be reusable?

Comment: Perhaps the photochemical decomposition of hydrogen peroxide solution might work? Only the first page of the paper is available here but it should give you an idea: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/j150320a025#
At a slight tangent you might find the Belousov-Zhabotinsky Reaction interesting
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBa4kgXI4Cg

Answer (score 2):

You can use any polymer which gets cured by exposure to light, if the curing results in a volumetric expansion, like [polyurethane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyurethane) foam.

In the case of polyurethane foam the curing is triggered by exposure to outer environment chemicals, but it just needs the right dose of organic chemistry to have it triggered by light. I.e. dentists use a blue/violet light to trigger curing into the dental filling they use nowadays, and photoresists are widely used in electronic manufacturing.

Photoresists in particular have certain doses to be activated, and that also goes in the direction you want.

Comment: Is this curing permanent or can it be reused?

Comment: @ALambentEye, usually curing is not reversible, at least for the polymers with commercial applications. You want your plastic to stay set, not to revert back.